# How do I do per-instance Azure Worker-Role configuration?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

In need to deploy 3 different worker roles but each needs it's own configuration (user name, password, etc.) to connect to a trading server.  I can't share the credentials across the instances.

If anyone knows how to accomplish this I would be very appreciative!

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you have 1 Worker Role with 3 instances? You should switch to 3 Worker Roles instead (different projects in Visual Studio). This allows you to configure each Worker Role independently (double click each Worker Role in the Azure project and go to the settings tab). Your common code can be in a shared assembly referenced by all 3 Worker Roles.

Comment: Wow!  How simple is that.  Sometimes the simple answers just stare us in the face...