# Azure Worker Role Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I need to to deploy 2 different worker role instances but each needs it's own configuration data (ID code, password, SenderCompID, etc.) to connect to a trading server. I can't share the credentials across the instances.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611547/how-do-i-do-per-instance-azure-worker-role-configuration. Sounds very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instance for any role (Worker or Web) are identical in terms of application based configuration. This is because all the instances are created from the same application will read exact same application configuration data.

If you write your application in a way that when application starts it reads data outside the machine (from azure storage, azure table or anything else outside the VM, mostly available on some server) and then configure itself then you could achieve your objective. You also need to provide instance specific data on server so each instance gets its own data. If I choose this option, i might use Azure table name i.e. Instance_ID# so each instance gets its own configuration and configured itself. This way I can modify the data any time on Azure Table and restart the role to load updated configuration. Other may have some other way to make it happen.

The other option is to have two role (worker or web) in same Azure application and while application code could be same in between two or more worker roles however you sure can configure them separately. Each of above options have its own pros and con.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply.  I am investigating the CurrentRoleInstance.Id route.